# How to play wav file as Stream using winmm.dll

Tags: c#, wav, playsound, winmm

Normally, I can play wav file using winmm.dll by passing filename as a parameter for **mciSendString** method. But now, I need to decrypt a wav file. Return object is a Stream so I cannot pass a filename.

Is there any way to pass a Stream for winmm.dll to play sound?

Comment: Winmm.dll doesn't know beans about .NET streams.  It is quite ably wrapped by the NAudio library, don't write your own.

Comment: @Alex You can save the stream to file.. Anyway [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) let you play wav streams